# Net::Twitter failing to install on Mac

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

I'm trying to update the perl [Net::Twitter](http://search.cpan.org/~mmims/Net-Twitter-4.00006/lib/Net/Twitter.pod) module in cpan, but it is in the build tests failing with an error:

> t/00-compile.t ................. 8/22 Attribute (deprecated) does not
>   pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'Bool' with
>   value CODE(0x7f9e29e25eb8) at
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm
>   line 1261
>
> ...
>
> Failed test 'Net::Twitter::Role::API::RESTv1_1 loaded ok' at
>   t/00-compile.t line 62.
>                   '' doesn't match '(?s-xim:^\s*Net::Twitter::Role::API::RESTv1_1 ok)'
>
> ...
>
> t/01_basic_v1_1.t .............. 1/785 Couldn't load class
>   (Net::Twitter::Role::API::RESTv1_1) because: Attribute (deprecated)
>   does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for
>   'Bool' with value CODE(0x7fbbac015f20) at
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm
>   line 1261

Comment: This is fairly hard to diagnose as is.  Could you provide 
the version of your xcode command line tools or at least clang version ( clang --version )
perl version ( perl --version ) 
cpan version ( cpan --version )
Net::Twitter CPAN module version you were trying to install?


I have 4.00006 installed with no problems.

Also, you can try installing CPAN::Reporter to provide feedback to module authors automatically